# Setando cursor na posição da string dentro do textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando fazer uma mascara para uma textbox manualmente, e estou tentando imitar a calculadora do Windows, aonde quando o usuário escreve `1000` o código automaticamente coloca `1.000` e quando eu dou um `txtPreco.Text =` o curso fica no começo da string `|1.000`. Quero colocar o cursor no final da string `1.000|` mas n sei qual método ou evento faz isso.

Comment: Mostre o código de como você está fazendo

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah1Rfu-NxWbqgaQH6G4GnIlCBtR8QQ
Metade do codigo n estava funcionando corretamente mas a primeira metade está funcionando , n como eu queria mas ta meio POG

Comment: Você deve [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/342956/edit) a pergunta e colocar o código diretamente nela - como link pode ficar inacessível no futuro, para outras pessoas lendo a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para manter o cursor no final do conteúdo você deve utilizar as propriedades `SelectionStart` e `SelectionLength` do `TextBox`.

**Veja o exemplo abaixo:**

```
private void txtPreco_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPreco.Text))
    {
        var valor = Int64.Parse(txtPreco.Text,                                
                           System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);


        txtPreco.Text = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR")
                                      "{0:N0}", valor);

        txtPreco.SelectionStart = txtPreco.Text.Length;
        txtPreco.SelectionLength = 0;
    }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]